# Haskell at a user level

Tags: macos, haskell, compiler-construction, interpreter

I love coding in Haskell, but often am on a computer where I cannot install software, and which has some restrictions about what you can run. I would like to write Haskell code and test it while on this computer. Does anyone know of version of Haskell, interpreted or compiled, written in Java, JavaScript, Ruby, Python, or another interpreted language available in the default install on a Mac? A standalone version of Haskell which can be installed at the user level works too, but compiling Haskell myself is not an option.

Comment: Small snippets of code, or multiple files?

Comment: Can't you just run a VM with e.g. Ubuntu on that mac, and thereupon install anything you like with administrator rights?

Comment: He can only run a VM if the administrator has provided him with the software to do that much...

Comment: I don't have VirtualBox but a kludge may be able to get me it. It would also be *extremely* slow. Define small snippets of code... I like to write 20-30 lines incl. type signatures per day

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The GHC binary distributions (the ones that come as tarballs, not installers) all can be installed locally trivially easily.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/ghc
make install
```

Then update your path to include $HOME/ghc/bin

If you want cabal, get the tarball from [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install), then untar it and run bootstrap.sh.

GHC works really well as a local install.  In fact, I never use it as a system install.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't even require I run any applications that I'm not supposed to since I can run Java Runtime and use my java-based terminal to execute all these commands. You get the 'Correct' mark for simplicity and first answer.

Comment: As someone who recently had to fight his OS (Ubuntu with old repos) to get rid of GHC6 to install GHC7: Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I do this on my workstation, too, so that the distribution I'm on (Debian in my case) doesn't suddenly start upgrading stuff without me noticing in a simple `apt-get upgrade`.

This solution installs a full `ghc` and `haskell-platform` as well as `~/.cabal` prefix.

First of all, I have a `~/local` directory that I use in order to put custom-compiled programs in my home directory. I usually dislike the `sudo make install` step, because I'm giving some random `Makefile` root access to my system, and that makes me feel queasy.

Then I download the ghc binary distribution from the [ghc site](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_4_2). NOTE that I linked you to 7.4.2. I hear there's some segfault bug on Mac OS X, but I'm not aware of the details. You should check that out or get the [newer ghc](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_1) instead, but be aware that there are many packages on hackage that are not yet fixed to work with 7.6. Also, ignore that "STOP!" warning, you're the 1% who actually want a non-distrib GHC binary.

You can just cd into the ghc directory, then do `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/haskell` or so, followed by `make install` (no compiling necessary, it's just going to install, not compile.)

At this point, you should add `~/local/haskell/bin` to your path. [Here's](https://github.com/adimit/config/blob/master/zshrc#L9) the code that I put in my `~/.zshrc`, which will add all `~/local/*/bin` directories to your path.

You can then get the Haskell Platform, and do the same `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/haskell && make && make install` dance. This step *will* need compilation. It means that you will need some header libraries installed. I find the random openGL headers that are necessary particularly annoying.

You can also of course skip haskell-platform, and just download [cabal-install](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install) directly, then install what you need. You should in any case not forget to add `~/.cabal/bin` to your `$PATH`!

Do a `cabal update` and you should be good to go.

NOTE: there's one important part that the binary distribution of GHC needs, which can sometimes be a pita on old Linux systems: libgmp. It's linked dynamically against it, and if you get some errors about the shared libgmp not being found on OS X, too, you can… well, ask that question in a comment, and I shall explain how to get there. Basically, you'll have to compile libgmp + deps yourself.

But I don't think that should be a problem on OS X. It's just been a problem on a couple old debian boxes I've tried this on.

Comment: Thanks for all the detail! I'd mark you correct if I could mark multiple as correct. If any of the stuff you said turns out to be essential to it working, I'll switch you to the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

For single files, you can use [codepad](http://codepad.org/).